# reverse proxy http to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I've configured an Apache server with SSL and reverse proxy to a tomcat

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:1443>
[...]
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://local.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://local.com:8080

SSLEngine on
[...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat is listening on 8080.
The issue is that the app on tomcat is redirecting the request (HTTP 302 Moved temporairly). For example, if I use the URL https:// domain.com:1443/folder, reverse proxy launch the request http:// local.com:8080/folder, then, the app redirect to "/subfolder", so the final request is: http://domain.com:1443/folder/subfolder. Result is a 400 Bad request error code, as the request is HTTP on my SSL port.

Do you know how I can fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to configure/modify your tomcat app, so that it redirects to https, not to http, when the original request was https too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plain http proxy, use `proxy_ajp`. Adapt the example below to match your needs, i.e. it is up to you to proxy everything to the container or only a namespace:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPassMatch ^/(your_app)(.*) ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2 ttl=120 ping=1
```

Ensure that `server.xml` in your `tomcat` configuration includes an AJP listener. The executor is optional.

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
          maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Yes I thinked to do this but I have a requirement to use HTTP instead of AJP...